# Best way to use actors when predicting a movie rating

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

So I'm trying to predict movie ratings based on several variables. I would like to include actors because that has a pretty large impact on the success of a movie. I've come up with several options.

1. Get the top 5 actors for each movie. Just have a unique integer that represents those actors and use that. I'm worried there are too many unique actors for a model to use this effectively though.
2. Take an average of all ratings of the movies that the actor performs in and use it like a key performance indicator. Have 5 separate columns for the top 5 actors in the movie with the KPI of each actor in the column.
3. Same as two except instead of five separate columns, combine them into a single value for the movie.

I'm thinking option two will be best. Is there a better way to go about this? If anyone has had any similar experiences I would love to hear how you solved it.

Comment: This probably highly depends on your exact method of prediction. An integer-coding does not sound promising for most supervised-learning approaches. Binary indicators (one column for each actor) is much more powerful (especially for non decision-tree based methods). Most methods (although not all) won't struggly even with 1 million columns as long as there are sparse (and they are in this case).

Comment: Ah, good to know. I thought of that as a possibility but I just assumed that would be too many columns. I'll look into that as another option. I'm probably going to try all three methods with different models and compare results.